# Does running a car air conditioning at full blast use more energy than on low?

Tags: thermodynamics

Judging from thermodynamics, I would assume the answer is yes. It would appear that maintaining a body at a lower temperature than the outside would induce greater heat conduction and thus more heat to be removed from the car.

I have read on random car mechanic sites that the air conditioning runs the same regardless of the setting. Thus, the only reasonable thing I can imagine is that the air conditioning is less efficient at lower settings.

How does the air-conditioning speed effect the energy expenditure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditional auto AC runs at one output . Many systems add heat if full cooling capacity is not wanted. Also the compressor will be cycled on / off if full cooling capacity is not needed.

Comment: Actually many/most commercial building in the US work the same way -  The AC is on or off. If the building is too cool , heat is added.

Comment: By letting heat in are you referring to letting heat dissipate into the car naturally like bang bang control? Or mixing it into the air? Bang bang would imply that turning the AC down would mean less energy spent. Mixing air is just generally inefficient

Comment: I mean hot radiator water is run into the heater core.